# Perturbing field off-resonance in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics

What are the main differences between resonant and off-resonant perturbations? Is there a a desired dynamic which results from atomic transitions from radiation off resonance as in the diagram below, or is it just theoretically more correct to model as if you are always off resonance?

[image]

Comment: *"Why is it so common ... aim for perturbing field which is off resonance?"* That's like asking why it's more common to buy vanilla instead of chocolate: one isn't better or more common, they're just different. Off resonant perturbations behave differently than resonant ones. Perhaps to ask an answerable question it would be better to give the precise context in which you have encountered off resonant perturbations.

Comment: It's also possible that the author you're reading does the off resonant case simply because you get the resonant case for free by putting $\Delta = 0$ :-)

Comment: @DanielSank What are common reasons chosen for off-resonance radiation? What different dynamics does it result it?

Comment: @John that's a rather broader question than really works well in this format. As Daniel says, you should provide the context in which you saw this, which will at least be frame things a bit.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Okay I edited it now.

Comment: The question still doesn't really make sense to me. There's no "desired dynamic" in any case. You pick the theoretical model depending on the real-life thing you want to understand. If I perturb the system on resonance, then I use the resonance model. If I perturb off-resonance, then I use the off-resonance model. For the sake of understanding a two level quantum system in general, it's convenient to work out the generally off-resonance case because you can always put $\Delta=0$ when you're done to see the resonance case.